# no match for operator [ ] (std::vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

So , i have made a graph using adjacency list , and i am trying to search it by using recursion. Got an awkward error message saying 'no match for operator []'. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


void search(vector <int> *v,int node)
{
    if (node==4)
    {
        cout<<"found 4";
        return;
    }

    vector <int> :: iterator it;
    if (!v[node].empty())
    {
        for (it=v[node].begin() ; it!=v[node].end() ; it++)
        {
            search(v,v[node][it]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> v[5];
    v[1].push_back(2);
    v[1].push_back(3);
    v[2].push_back(4);
    v[2].push_back(5);
    search (v,1);
}
```

Comment: `v` is not a `std::vector`. It's a pointer. Pointers also happen to support `[index]` syntax, but to do it properly you better dereference the pointer first.

Comment: change: `vector <int> *v` --> `vector <int> &v`

Comment: You passing `vector <int> *` as a pointer parameter, sou you must defeference it to call the `operator[]()` function.

Comment: `v[node][it]`: here `it` is an *iterator*. It is not an index. You cannot put it inside square brackets.

Comment: Its working now. I have changed it to  v[ node ] [*it ] . Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mixing `std::vector` with C style arrays? `std::array<std::vector<int>, 5>` is less error prone. A `std::multi_map<int, int>` does it in one container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `it` is an iterator.

```
vector <int> :: iterator it;
```

This can not be used to index into an array like this:

```
search(v,v[node][it]); // Expecting an index not an iterator.
```

I think what you want is to de-reference the iterator.

```
search(v, *it);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the node is not out of bounds.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void search(vector<int> *v, int count, int node)
    {
       if (node == 4)
       {
        cout << "found 4";
       return;
    }

    if (node < count && !v[node].empty())
    {
        for (auto it = v[node].begin(); it != v[node].end(); it++)
        {
            search(v, count, *it);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> v[5];
   v[1].push_back(2);
   v[1].push_back(3);
   v[2].push_back(4);
   v[2].push_back(5);

   search(v, sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]), 1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `v` is a *pointer* (Which represents an array) to a vector. To access the subscript operator, you have to access the C Style Array first using `v[first_index]`. Then you have to index whatever returned object you get from the first indexing. However, you shouldn't even be using pointers for vectors. If you want to modify a container, then pass it by reference. If you want to store an array of vectors, then I recommend that you just nest them (Although this may be bad for memory, so you can create a 1D vector and compute indices).

Comment: Isn't that one of the possible ways to pass arrays as arguments ?. Link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

Comment: Yes, but it isn't the best way since arrays decay to pointers at the first opportunity and lose knowledge of their size. Using a `vector` is a much better idea.

Comment: But why am i getting an error message for this ? What's the syntactical error in this ?

Comment: OP has a C-style *array* of vectors.

Comment: @n.m. Fixed explanation